# What is a child tunnel?

Tags: vpn, tunnel, terminology, point-to-point

I only heard this term today, but it was explained to me as a point-to-point VPN (so, two routers with a VPN tunnel established between them) and a firewall configured to only allow certain hosts to talk to certain other hosts (per their ip address); is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you think you're referring to an **IPSEC Child Security Association (SA)**?  It's described by the specifications as a *child* and even has some related notification types.

To expand, Child SAs are created for *policy-based IPSEC VPNs* as a result of how they are implemented by routers.  If you have the following configuration for a tunnel, two Child SAs are created within each router, and each SA has its own cryptographic state:

```
        VPN                          VPN
      Router A ---------IPSEC------ Router B
     /       \                        |
    /         \                       |
   /           \                      |
192.0.2.0/24  198.51.100.0/24     203.0.113.0/24
```

Policy-Based VPN Child SAs (possible; won't always exist):

- 192.0.2.0/24 <-> 203.0.113.0/24
- 198.51.100.0/24 <-> 203.0.113.0/24

Fits the description, but not sure of the context of your question.

Comment: That also what came to my mind reading the question. It is the more likely explanation. However in you example most router consider there's only 2 -bi directional- child SA.

Comment: I must have remembered wrong.  I'll correct my answer!